# Decrease Backlight Below Minimum

Tags: brightness, backlight

I have this laptop that doesn't handle the backlight very well.

In */etc/default/grub*, I have added a `acpi_backlight=vendor` function to get it to work at all. Which is cool, and the backlight now actually works, but the minimum backlight setting is still pretty high.

Is there any way to decrease the backlight below minimum? I don't mind having to type in the terminal to do that, as I won't need to do it often (just at night etc.)

Answer (score 47):

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Enter the following command:

   ```bash
   cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   ```
3. Write down the resulting value (12421 in my case).
4. Divide value by 6 and write it down (2070 in my case).
5. Enter the following in the terminal, replacing ***`2070`*** with *your* value:

   ```bash
   sudo su -c "echo 2070 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
   ```
6. Close Terminal.
7. For future usage of the last command, open Terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> together, start typing `brightness`. When the last command appears, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It works for me on a Samsung NC110 with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook Air (integrated Graphics only). However, pressing any brightness level button seems to reset this setting, i.e. pressing "brighter" does not increment from the brightness setting applied in the terminal, but from the "usual" minimum brightness that you achieve using the keyboard. Therefore increasing the brightness after applying this command results in a huge brightness increase.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh. This setting resets itself automatically every few minutes. So you got to reapply it over and over. In it's current format this is not a practical solution :( Running it as a script periodically seems overkill though. I hope there's a better way...

Comment: @king_julien, check my answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/394400), at the provided link I tell about some settings that may avoid resets. I'm not suffering any reset of this setting at my macbook pro. I suspect the reset has to do with the boot parameters. Since I've changed them, I'm not suffering a "reset" after unlocking the machine.

Comment: Why divide by 6?  On my machine I could reduce this value much more...

Comment: `sudo su -c "echo 2070 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"` is the key, the number can go as down as 0. I use 80 on pitch black rooms. On 14.04.

Comment: When I try values between 0 and 1 I get an error: echo: write error: Invalid argument
Is there a solution for that?

Comment: This used to work in Ubuntu 16.04, but doesn't anymore in Ubuntu 16.10 :-(

Comment: Wow I had no idea my screen brightness had this much granularity. I don't know why you're dividing by 6 here, but on my laptop it seems to be that any number works. The normal lowest brightness was 376, but I found 20 to be very nice in a dark room at night.

Answer (score 39):

None of the answers here worked for me (on a Dell Precision 5510). The output from `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` for me was `1` and setting it any lower completely turned the screen off.

I finally found a solution from the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181501/27780):

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness .3
```

I was also able to get this to work on my external monitor (attached via a display port dock), and reduce it below the minimum brightness allowed by the hardware controls on the monitor:

```
xrandr --output DP1-1 --brightness .6
```

Note that your display might not be eDP1 (or DP1-1), but you can list all available displays by hitting tab twice after `--output`, or from `xrandr -q` which shows which ones are currently connected. Tweak the value for brightness, i.e., .4, .5, etc until you find a level that works for you.

Comment: How do you make this change permanent?

Comment: is there a way to get nightlight with this as well?  when i use it, nightlight goes off and i get bluer tints

Comment: `OMG` `OMG` first time in my life I faced the power of Linux hack like this, and I use Linux for many years, `xrandr --output eDP-1  --brightness .6` this did the trick from me BTW .3 were like someone turned off the like, now I have beautiful semi Black/White screen to watch .

Answer (score 4):

Try to override the min brightness manually with

1. `sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
2. Change the value in this file to 0 (clear and type 0 if value is already 0).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
4. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.

This works for me. You can also try `sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'`

I am still looking for a more robust approach. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognise the folder/file. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, if that makes any sense to you. Thanks for caring to answer, though.

Comment: I tried doing suggested. However the brightness still remains the same. In my case it was already `0` . Although I cleared and reentered as suggested.

Comment: This file does not exists in 12.04.

Comment: Different GPUs / hardware have it in different places

Answer (score 3):

The Gnome Shell extension [Alpha Tint](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4624/alphatint/) has solved the issue for me in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Wayland).

Comment: This is the only one which worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Ubuntu but Debian, but sometimes (second screen plugin, gnome restart) the brightness drops to zero. So I've created an inotify enabled application (it consumes zero cputime while there is no change in brightness) and when there is the change and it is changed to zero (or lower some predefined level, which you can specify) it sets the brightness to some default level, which you can also specify.

Please find it at my github page: https://github.com/nuccy/zero_brightness_fixer

Answer (score 1):

Install [xbacklight](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight) by typing the following in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then:

```
xbacklight -percentage
```

replace the word "percentage" with the number of your choice to decrease the backlight from 1 to 99. In contrast, you can also do:

```
xbacklight +percentage
```

to increase the brightness by replacing the word "percentage" with a number between 1 and 100. For more information, run the following in the terminal:

```
xbacklight -help
```

I know that this is probably too late, but I hope it helps :)

Comment: This does not decrease the backlight *below* minimum. When I'm already an the minium and just step `-1`, the display shuts off.

Comment: Didn't do anything.no matter what setting I used.

Answer (score 1):

The Gnome Shell Extension [Soft-brightness](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1625/soft-brightness/) did the trick for me.

Comment: yes it did the trick for me too!

Answer (score 0):

This app works for me for decreasing brightness well beyond the usual https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness

Comment: Looks interesting. Care to share your binary?

Comment: @TenLeftFingers sorry, dont have that machine now.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is a slider utility to set `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`:

- https://gitlab.com/oblitum/backlight

Works for my intel based MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a lot of GPUs:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/$(ls /sys/class/backlight/)/brightness
```

For Ryzen APU's its:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
```