# Minimum Brightness Level too Bright/High on an Asus UL-50

Tags: brightness, asus

the minimum brightness level is too bright for me.  I did take a look at the following post:

[Decrease Backlight Below Minimum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum)

but the solution mentioned did not work for me.  Before using ubuntu, I tried linux mint, and was able to adjust my screen brightness much lower.  I do have the brightness app installed on my toolbar, but even at the minimum setting, it is too bright/high.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

A Linux Newbie

Comment: This is an Asus UL-50 15.6 inch laptop

Answer (score 2):

1- Open Terminal

2- Enter the following command:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

3- Write down the resulting value (12421 in my case)

4- Divide value by 6 and write it down (2070 in my case)

5- Enter the following in the terminal, replacing 2070 with your value:

```
sudo su -c "echo 2070 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
```

6- Close Terminal

7- For future usage of last command, open terminal, press Ctrl and R together, start typing "brightness". When last command appears just press Enter.

It does work for me (Samsung NC110, Ubuntu 12.04)

---

Comment: This setting resets itself automatically every few minutes. So you got to reapply it over and over. In it's current format this is not a practical solution :( Running it as a script periodically seems overkill though. I hope there's a better way...

Comment: @king_julien check my answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/394400), at the provided link I tell about some settings that may avoid resets. I'm not suffering any reset of this setting at my macbook pro. I suspect the reset has to do with the boot parameters. Since I've changed them, I'm not suffering a "reset" after unlocking the machine.