# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS can't change screen brightness

Tags: brightness

I use the Fn+ buttons with the -sun and +sun on them, and the brightness doesn't seem to change. I have also tried to change the brightness on the bar at the top right. Neither of these seems to work, I googled the problem, but it doesn't seem to be for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I could change the screen brightness when I switched to windows 10.

This is the link I was looking at but for the previous versions of Ubuntu.Will the solutions they propose still work or do I have to find another way?
[I cannot change the screen brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228816/i-cannot-change-the-screen-brightness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It was the second answer provided by Renato Miotto.

[Ubuntu 20.04 brightness adjust not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230937/ubuntu-20-04-brightness-adjust-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install brightness-controller`

   Try the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing intel graphics drivers.
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
And then use xbacklight command like
xbacklight -inc 25

Comment: I tried but xbacklight did not seem to make a difference with brightness