# Ubuntu – 18.04 can’t adjust screen brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 gen2

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, screen, brightness, thinkpad

I have tried different ways but it still doesn't work. I have also attempted to change the grub file. [Screebrightness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1TMY.png)

Comment: Please be more specific. What did you try?
`

Comment: I have also created a new configuration file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/. I have also tried to install brightness Controller - ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller. @ToDo

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/228835/27968

Comment: I have tried every method. Still not work. Is it because my laptop is running AMD RYZEN 7 instead of Intel i series @ToDo

Comment: Include that information in your question to get answers.