# How to fix brightness set to zero at startup?

Tags: startup, brightness

Everytime I reboot my pc, my brightness is at the lowest value, making the screen really dark at startup. How can I prevent this from happening? I would like to have higher brightness at startup.

this is the laptop that I have: lenovo Yoga Slim 7 14ARE05

cpu: AMD® Ryzen 7 4800u with radeon graphics × 16

gpu: AMD® Renoir

memory: 16 GB LPDDR4X

Edit: Desktopenviroment is GNOME 3.36.5 and my ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try these possibilities: https://askubuntu.com/a/228835/27968

Comment: Ah, I ran into some problems when modifying GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor". After updating grub and rebooting, the screen became black and I was unable to change the brightness. I think I was in the "log in" screen as I could change the volume (with sound confirmation), but I can't see anything

Comment: Thank you @BeastOfCaerbannog

I've managed to restore the file in /etc/default/grub, then I tried the second method and modified ` GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" ` to ` GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux
acpi_backlight=vendor" `. But that also didn't work for me @ToDo. I got this warning message when trying out both methods: "GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata."