# reduce laptop screen brigtness below minimum

Tags: laptop, brightness

This is not duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/560445/dim-screen-past-the-minimum-on-ubuntu . I have already tried the solution mentioned in the above article.
my laptop configuration is dell inspiron 1440. I wanted to reduce my laptop screeen brightness in ubuntu below the minimum level that can be set using system settings. I usually set my screen brightness to an ultra low level, as it hurts my eyes. I have already searched for the solution online and found related posts

https://superuser.com/questions/323476/can-i-fine-tune-my-screen-brightness

[Decrease Backlight Below Minimum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum)

https://superuser.com/questions/560445/dim-screen-past-the-minimum-on-ubuntu

[Decrease Backlight Below Minimum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum)

The problem is that in my case the screen brightness value in the file /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness is already 0. I have tried installing backlight and setting it to 0, and overwriting the value again as described in one of the posts above. However, none of it helps. I am currently using the latest version of ubuntu 13.10 . Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, but what I use is an app called RedShift, which gives the screen a redshit and is much easier on the eyes. If you do give it a try, don't kick it immediately. It takes a while to get used to.

Comment: you can also try flux http://justgetflux.com/linux.html and I'd also play with the contrast as well.

Comment: @Jeremy Redshift adjusts the picture (contrast) before it's being output to the screen. This reduces contrast and is not the proper way to reduce the brightness (amount of light).

Comment: Not all displays allow lower brightness settings. Perhaps it's just not possible for your model to reduce it further.