# How to set brightness level even lower than default minimum?

Tags: brightness

I am an ex-Windows user, I noticed that minimum level of screen brightness on ubuntu is way brighter than minimum level on windows when I was using it on the same hardware. I was wondering if I can set the brightness level on ubuntu at a level even lower than the minimum level it allows, because default minimum brightness on ubuntu is too brighter for me. Is there any tweak with system settings which I can employ to reduce my screen brightness even further than what default system settings allow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the following file -

```
sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

and change the value to a lower value.

For more methods, refer to question:[Decrease Backlight Below Minimum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum).

Comment: thanks man, it did the trick for me, but for those who want to employ this tweak, don't change the value to zero, it will turn the screen off completely, try some bigger value and adjust as per your needs.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: can anybody tell me why can't I edit this file using vim editor even using sudo?

Comment: FYI, the path could be different depending on the computer. For me it was `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness`, so you might need to go to `/sys/class/backlight/` and see what folder you have. Also, my lowest default screen brightness was 2, and when I changed it to 1, it was only a little dimmer, and it seems it doesn't take decimals, so I'll keep looking for a way to make it ultra-dim.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

as a Kernelparameter. I had such a problem, too. This parameter solved it for me.
You can read here for [Kernelbootparameters.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).