# Reducing brighness below minimum 16.04

Tags: 16.04, laptop, brightness, backlight

Is it possible to change the screen brightness below minimum under 16.04?

Before updating (on 14.04) I could change the brightness as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum). I have also tried using xbackligt without any success.

I have tried but does not work very well for me to change the colors to make the screen appear darker.

Comment: Bad news for you: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/175291/195768) to the question you linked to definitely works on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That was bad news. I have integrated intel HD graphics: `ls /sys/class/backlight/` gives the output: acpi_video0@  intel_backlight@

Comment: I also have integrated Intel HD graphics however: `ls /sys/class/backlight/` only shows `intel_backlight`. Perhaps your extra `acpi_video` is complicating matters?

Comment: The two systems seem to work in parallel. I tested changing the backlight by editing the corresponding values, and they both behave the same. It seems that the update changed how the brightness value is interpreted, now zero is the lowest allowed, and not the lowest possible.