# DELL XPS 15 9550 minimum brightness

Tags: dell, laptop, brightness, backlight

Brigtness in my dell xps 15 9550 is to high, when I lower it to minimum, it still is to high. I want to be able to lower the brightness even to 0.

I tried what is suggested in here:

[Decrease Backlight Below Minimum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104162/decrease-backlight-below-minimum/175291#175291)

But when i execute the first command, i get the value of 1, and if i change to 0 the screen has no brightness at all. When i increse the brightness value, the minimum is still the one i had at first, and it is just to high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make the brightness lower than the default minimum, but Desktop Dimmer is a reasonable workaround that I use on a regular basis. Running it will dim your screen however much you want. Desktop Dimmer is available in Ubuntu Software center.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you. I read alot in my dell, i truly love this laptop, but brightness made it imposible to read.

Comment: Probably outdated. Check 'Brightness' in Software Center, which can be accessed in terminal by 'lxqt-config' (comments), worked for me. (Ubuntu 20.04, Dell XPS 15 9500)