# How to increase bass *solely* using terminal commands (*no* installation of any software) (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: command-line, sound

At first, I was looking for a solution to decrease my screen’s brightness. Many solutions, however, just recommended to install this or that software in order to solve the problem. But [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/175291) managed to set the brightness of my screen **without** installing any software.

Therefore, I wanted to ask if there are similar ways to deal with the low bass issue. That is: Is there a command which lets me check what bass value is currently configured and is there another one that allows me to change that value?

Comment: What is "the low bass" issue? Do you mean you want to control _sound volume_?

Comment: I mean that if I, for example, watch a video on YouTube, the bass isn’t very high – and I have no clue how to change this. Of course, I could download the video and play it with the help of the VLC player which then allows me to change the bass values but this is not a very practical solution.

Comment: Please advise which flavor and version number of Ubuntu is in use, by clicking on the `edit` link above and left, and adding that vital information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! [Cryptopat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/211409/cryptopat) wrote in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164476/how-to-control-equalizer-within-command-line

The pulseaudio equalizer [included in the packages for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sound/) and some other earlier versions has settings in the user file `~/.config/pulse/equalizerrc`

To install it, please execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

To display it:

```
cat ~/.config/pulse/equalizerrc
```

Increasing the 5th band of the equalizer by 10DB, and immediately hear the change, is accomplished from a shell prompt with:

```
sed -i '19s/.*/10.0/' ~/.config/pulse/equalizerrc | pulseaudio-equalizer toggle
```

The editor [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) will replace line numbered 19, with a 10 db bump in the config file; then the equalizer is restarted to hear the result.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04, but when I type `cat ~/.config/pulse/equalizerrc`, it says that the file or directory `/home/username/.config/pulse/equalizerrc` and the command `pulseaudio-equalizer` cannot be found.

Comment: To install it, please execute this command: `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer`